# Error while trying to extract company data from google finance through R programming

Tags: r

```html
> library(quantmod)
Loading required package: xts
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Loading required package: TTR
Version 0.4-0 included new data defaults. See ?getSymbols.
Learn from a quantmod author: https://www.datacamp.com/courses/importing-and-managing-financial-data-in-r

Attaching package: ‘quantmod’

The following object is masked from ‘package:FinCal’:

    lineChart

> appl.p<-getSymbols("AAPL",src="google",env=NULL)
‘getSymbols’ currently uses auto.assign=TRUE by default, but will
use auto.assign=FALSE in 0.5-0. You will still be able to use
‘loadSymbols’ to automatically load data. getOption("getSymbols.env")
and getOption("getSymbols.auto.assign") will still be checked for
alternate defaults.

This message is shown once per session and may be disabled by setting 
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE). See ?getSymbols for details.
Error in download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=AAPL&startdate=Jan+01,+2007&enddate=Apr+17,+2018&output=csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  :
  cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=AAPL&startdate=Jan+01,+2007&enddate=Apr+17,+2018&output=csv': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

Hello, I'm very new to R programming.
Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Is their a package that needs to be installed?

Or maybe there is a problem with the internet? 
I cant figure it out!

Comment: Did they stop providing these data? No one seems to know for sure. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/o1jgHoR4y_k;context-place=forum/docs

Comment: Related discussion: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/221 It appears google no longer provides this data.